# cocoa-How to set status bar app left click event?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm new to objective-c programming and I'm trying to make a status bar application right now.

I only know how to set a dropdown menu to show when click on the status bar item.

However, what I want is to show a `panel` when left clicked and show the `menu` when right clicked, just like the way `Bartender 2` acts.

I've referred this [demo](https://github.com/shpakovski/Popup) but I could hardly figure out what it does.

I use `xib` to build my UI. I have three `.xib` files: `MainMenu`, `Preferences` and `MainPanel`.

`AppDelegate.h`

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property NSStatusItem *statusItem;

@end
```

`AppDelegate.m`

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Menu.h" //Menu is a ViewController for Menu.xib

@interface AppDelegate ()

//@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window; //I don't know what is this for

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize statusItem;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

//I initiate my statusItem here
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    self.statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];

    self.statusItem.title = @"T";

    // you can also set an image
    //self.statusBar.image =

    self.statusItem.highlightMode = YES;

//I tried to use these code to set the left click action
    [statusItem setTarget:self];
    [statusItem setAction:@selector(showMenu:)];
}

-(void)showMenu{
    Menu* menuVC = [[Menu alloc] initWithNibName:@"Menu" bundle:nil];
//Don't know what to do next...
}
@end
```

I tried to use

`[menuVC showWindow];`

but it is not right.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571323/how-can-i-show-nsmenu-at-mouse-cursor) post for information about drawing an `NSMenu` at a given `NSPoint` (use `popUpContextMenu:withEvent:forView:` instead of `showWindow`).

I'll also point out that in the example you linked, the author modularizes his project into different components, following the MVC pattern. There is a component for the menu controller and view (it doesn't look like he just displays an `NSMenu`), as well as the panel controller and view. You may want to think about how you can organize your project to follow the conventions of MVC.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to follow the MVC pattern. But I'm not quite familiar with it yet and what I'm working on is the first project I do. What I have now is a `AppDelegate` class and three `xib` files with three `ViewController` connecting to each of them. But I'm confused, which class is to response to my click action? The `AppDelegate` or the viewcontrollers?